# Database to be used in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, windows-phone-8

I am a new member in the field of building application in Windows Phone 8. What is/are the database local server to be used in building apps for windows phone 8 devices. 
I have did some researched and found out about LINQ to SQL but I am not sure if that will be the one to be used for database connectivity. For example, MySQL to be used for web base system. is LINQ to SQL the same type as MySQL? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Probably use SQLite database which is widely used for Android and IOS also. 
Seems similar with this post
[linq to sql (Local database for Windows Phone) better ? (OR) A sqlite-net version for mobile better ?? for windows phone 8 local database creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701710/linq-to-sql-local-database-for-windows-phone-better-or-a-sqlite-net-versio)